# Retrieve count of method parameters and name of parameters in java

Tags: java

Retrieve count of method parameters and name of parameters in java.

```
public void verifyAboutUsPageUrlValidation(Integer inputNumber, Boolean expectedResult) throws Exception {
    //JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
    //System.out.println((String)js.executeScript("arguments.length"));
    logger= report.startTest("verify AboutUs Page Url");
    logger.assignCategory("Rgression");

    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test start");

    System.out.println(inputNumber + " " + expectedResult);
    AboutUsPage about= new AboutUsPage(driver);
    about.CheckAboutUsPageUrlValidation(logger);    
    logger.log(LogStatus.INFO, "Test end");  
}
```

Comment: I think you need to add a question to this post? It's not really clear what you want.

Answer (score 1):

## Reflection

To get the count of parameters of a method you can use [reflection](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/), specifically [`Method.getTypeParameters`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getTypeParameters()).